# How to read OpenCV camera by name/ID instead of device index?

Tags: python, windows, opencv, camera, video-capture

In python you can do

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(index)
```

to open a webcam at `index` where `index` is a number ranging from 0,1,2,3...

But if I have multiple cameras and the order is arbitrary, my camera accessing code will be unreliable.

Is there a way to open a specific camera with a name or ID using OpenCV on Windows 10? How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this library and it seems to work: https://github.com/pvys/CV-camera-finder

Might be interesting to check this too: https://github.com/econsystems/opencv

Comment: note: the first link relies on microsoft media foundation (MSMF), so it will only work on windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can start looking at udev rules for linux and the look the windows equivalent for the same.

udev rules lets you configure usb devices, as soon as they are connected to the port, using unique attributes stored on the device such as vendor ID, serial number, product ID etc.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) For example you can add a code example.