# Displaying all video input device names in tkinter Python

Tags: python, opencv

Im trying to make a drop down menu that shows all the available webcams and their names and lets you choose one, and then it displays the current feed from that webcam.
Does anyone know how to do this?
I dont want to use the windows api because i think that just finds the cameras in device manager, but im using virtual webcams as well so I need them to be detected.
Thanks

```
import cv2
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

def enumerateCameras():
    camera_list = []
    for i in range(10):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(i)
        if cap.isOpened():
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret:
                camera_list.append(f"Webcam {i}")
        cap.release()
    return camera_list

camera_list = enumerateCameras()
label = tk.Label(root, text="\n".join(camera_list))
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

But it just displays the webcam number not the name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read OpenCV camera by name/ID instead of device index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61077265/how-to-read-opencv-camera-by-name-id-instead-of-device-index)

Comment: opencv assigns indices in some unspecified manner. the system **also** may assign names/indices to devices in an unspecified or random manner. there is no way with opencv to make sure you get the same camera after a reboot.